# Open iTunes Store within IOS App just like in twitter music

Tags: objective-c, itunes

This code separately open Itunes .
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/gravity-voice-performance/id631561174?uo=4"];
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
I want to open Album page within ios app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`SKStoreProductViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011852).